# [google-drive-api]How to handle google API's get() alt=media response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, google-drive-api

Ive been trying to implement the drive API in my angularjs app. I want to download a pdf file so I use this following code.

```
$scope.getFile = function(id) {
  console.log(id);
  //console.log(fileId);
  if (id != null) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      'fileId': id,
      'alt': 'media'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log('response: ' + resp);
    });
  }
}
```

but my console.log prints 'false'. I dont know why its really making me crazy I checked the network tab in inspect element and found the response correctly as a base64 string.

[image: screenshot of response]

I also called `atob(resp)` which says that the text to be decoded is not correctly encoded. but i used an online base64 decoder and it works perfectly the pdf is opening. please help me im stuck here

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `then` instead of `execute`:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': id,
    'alt': 'media'
});
request.then(function(resp) {
    console.log('response: ' + resp);
});
```